# Calling textures dynamically

Tags: java, android

I am iterating through a list that contains ints and I need them to link up with Textures that I have.

An example is

```
          for (int i = 0; i<spellsRectangles.size(); i++){
              if(selectedSpells.contains(i){
                  drawSpellFromRect(Asset."spell"+i+"Light",i);
              }else{
                  drawSpellFromRect(Asset."spell"+i+"Dark",i);
              }
          }

          drawSpellFromRect(TextureRegion tr, int i){
              spriteBatcher.draw(tr,spellsRectangles.get(i).x,spellsRectangles.get(i).y,spellsRectangles.get(i).height,spellsRectangles.get(i).width)
          }
```

spellRectangles is an arraylist of rectangles

The textures are all already made and I just need to access them. Is there a way to use and iterator to call the textures. Instead of going to texture1, texture2, texture3, ect.

I have looked and realize I cannot create variables dynamically but can I call them?

Comment: Can you put some code in question which will help us understand better ?

Comment: Sure thing,I altered my question to show some code. The TextureRegions are already created but now I need to call them and decide which ones to display and at what positions. This information is in the spellsRectangles arraylist. Is that more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the textures into an ArrayList seemed to solve the problem. It made the process of iterating and picking TextureRegions easier.